# Webpage displaying correctly in chrome, not in firefox

Tags: html, css

As shown in the images, the background image of my webpage fits on chrome, but for some reason, the image does not scale correctly in firefox even though the window sizes are the same. Worse yet, when I shrink the window width, it does not scale well at all. How am I supposed to know the window size of the browser someone is using?

UPDATE here are the images. First is chrome, second is firefox

https://www.flickr.com/photos/125343138@N07/24491082235/in/dateposted-public/

https://www.flickr.com/photos/125343138@N07/24464890356/in/dateposted-public/

Here is the stylesheet

```
.nav {

list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: fill;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

.nav li {

display: inline;
padding: 20px 10px;    
}

.nav li a {

color: whitesmoke;
padding: 14px 190px;
font-family: 'futura';
font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;

}

.jmb {

background-image: url('https://farm2.staticflickr.com /1600/24149223706_da584c8c45_o.jpg');
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position: 00px 37px;
}

.jmb h5 {

  font-family: 'Yellowtailregular';
  font-size: 105px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 170px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;

}

.jmb div p
{
font-size: 27px;
font-family: 'futura';
margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: -24px;
word-wrap: break-word; 
width: 27%;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;    

}
```

Comment: What images are you talking about?

Comment: Only Chrome and Safari support the `webkit` related styles and toolkits.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you'll only really know what browser size your user is using based on your metrics and what you know about your demographic. I'd start with something small and scale up higher as you go till you reach that large desktop size.

AMACB is right about the webkit support so some of your code might require a moz prefix to work correctly. you can find documentation on the support for that here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_support_chart

As far as covering your entire given area, I don't see a live link but my first suggestion would be to try with this:

```
background-size: cover
```

That should take the image and map it to the size of the object its in although you may not get the aspect ratio right. Thats when you might consider using media queries and/either different images or different positioning to alter how its displayed. Be sure to check your markup as well to make sure that there isn't an object that is on the border of your page as well that would prevent the image from reaching the end.

Comment: That being said, I don't think there's any demographic that will be browsing the web at 5470x2617. That image you're referencing for the background of the .jmb class is 7.5MB, which is HUUUGE for a webpage background. I'm on a fairly fast connection, and it still took me a full minute to download it. You should be able to reduce its size quite a bit and still comfortably fit any realistic screen without stretching.

Comment: He's right. Give a quick open with your photo editor of choice and I'd crop it. I personally think the size I'm giving you can often be too big as well, but its the first size I try in development before I lower it more to optimize. 1920x1080. Then use an image cruncher to make it smaller in size, and later you can use a CDN to lower load times as well.

Comment: @AidanBoyle Got it, I cropped it to 1920x1280 to preserve aspect ratio. should I just shrink my browser window and resize/rearrange everything to accommodate that size? I was originally viewing it on a 4k 24 inch mac so perhaps that is why I was able to get away with the huge image. Also, if someone is using a slightly different window size, how do I account for that, so that the tiniest adjustment doesn't make my menu bar look ugly?

Comment: Well, one of the best methods would be having a few css breakpoints outlined. Some really good breakpoints are provided on https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities if you look carefully you can find pixel values where designers will typically find points to start altering the design to compensate for device changes. If you write media queries with those values you can alter what your position for the image is, or even what image is shown there. Start with the size for a phone and work your way up. Thats your safest bet.